# How do I adjust the Date Format when it is in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can't figure out how to isolate only the Date variable in an array that is pulling all of the keys from MYSQL. I want to make it format %M %d. How can I pull it out of $dataFields array modify it then put it back in? The Key is "Date".

```
include('include/connect.php');

$table='currentJobs';

$sql="SELECT * FROM `".$table."`";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$dbLink);

$data=array();
$d=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dataFields=array();

    while(list($key,$value)=each($row)){
        $dataFields[]='<td class="'.$key.'" >'.$row[$key].'</td>';
        if ($d==0){
            $dataKeys[]='<th class="'.$key.'" >'.$key.'</th>';
        }
    }

    if ($d==0){
        $data[$d]='<tr>'.join('',$dataKeys).'<th class="actions">Actions</th></tr>';
        $d++;
    }   

    $data[$d]='<tr>'.join('',$dataFields).'<td>
        <a href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a></td></tr>';
    $d++;
}
mysql_free_result($result);

if ($d>0){
    echo '<table class="sortable">'.join('',$data).'</table>';
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry, data was not found';
}

mysql_close($dbLink);
```

It is currently Displaying:

```
Date    Name    Phone   Bike_Year   Bike_Model  Current_Status  Service_Type ▴  Mechanic    Revenue Notes   Actions
0000-00-00  Test User   206-555-5555    2001    FLHRI   Checked In  Spec Service Interval   Johhny  840.30      Update
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is less efficient then just modifying the format within the SQL as suggested by JOE LEE. But either way works, whichever you prefer should work.

```
if($key == 'Date'){
    $dataFields[]='<td class="'.$key.'" >'.date('M d',strtotime($row[$key])).'</td>';
} else {
    $dataFields[]='<td class="'.$key.'" >'.$row[$key].'</td>';
}
```

or compact:

```
$dataFields[] = $key == 'Date' ? date('M d',strtotime($row[$key])) : $row[$key];
```

Look here for the date format options:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT 
    date_format(date, '%M %d') AS date,
    Name,Phone,Bike_Year,Bike_Model,Current_Status  Service_Type,Mechanic,Revenue,Notes
FROM `".$table."`";
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach.